# Send mail with PHP using the label of the value in the answer

Tags: php, html, email, label

I want to let my visitors check some checkboxes.
When they submit the form I would like to check which checkboxes are checked and then send an email to the visitor. 
My problem is that I don't want to show the value but the label.

So if someone checks for example the "bike" checkbox I want to send an email with text containing the `$bike` but I want to show the label instead of the value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bike">
<label for="bike">This is my bike</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="car">
<label for="car">This is my car</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="bus">
<label for="bus">This is my bus</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="plane">
<label for="plane">This is my plane</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="train">
<label for="train">This is my train</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? I only see part of an HTML form and no code intended to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are not passed to PHP. You'll need logic on the backend to turn `train` into `This is my train`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just build a one-page execution/form class. The `__construct()` is just taking hard coded values, but you could feed a database connection and return an array there as well.

```
        class   Vehicles
            {
                protected $array;

                public  function __construct()
                    {
                        $this->array['vehicle']['bike']     =   'This is my bike';
                        $this->array['vehicle']['car']      =   'This is my car';
                        $this->array['vehicle']['bus']      =   'This is my bus';
                        $this->array['vehicle']['plane']    =   'This is my plane';
                        $this->array['vehicle']['train']    =   'This is my train';
                    }

                public  function Form()
                    { ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="true" /><?php
        foreach($this->array as $type => $kind) {
                foreach($kind as $key => $value) {?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $type; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <label for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></label>
                <?php }
            } ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <?php       }

                public  function SendMail($email)
                    {
                        if(isset($_POST['command']) && $_POST['command'] == 'true') {

                                foreach($_POST['vehicle'] as $value) {
                                        if(isset($this->array['vehicle'][$value]))
                                            $selection[]    =   $this->array['vehicle'][$value];
                                    }

                                $subject    =   "Subject: Vehicle Selected";
                                $message    =   implode("\r\n",$selection);
                                $header     =   "From: Automator Send<email@from.addr>";
                                if(mail($email,$subject,$message,$header))
                                    echo 'Sent';
                            }
                        else
                            $this->Form();
                    }
            }
            // Initiate Class
            $Automaker  =   new Vehicles();
            // Run main function 
            $Automaker->SendMail('email@address.com'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$translate = array (
    'bike'=>'This is my bike',
    ...
);
//    Assuming vehicle has been declared vehicle[] and is passed as an array:

foreach ($_POST ['vehicle'] as $v)
{
    $label = $translate [$v];
    ....
}
```

Labels are not input fields and so are not sent to the server. Why would they? They don't change and the server knows what they are!

In all probability, you would have used the translate array to generate the fields in the first place:

```
foreach ($translate as $value=>$label)
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle[]' value='$value'>\n"
    echo "<label for='$value'>$label</label>\n"
}
```